# SMSReciever not getting texts in android

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to set up my app to execute a service when a certain text is received however i dont think my reciever class is even getting messages. I have a log set up right at the beginning of my onrecieved method

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("SMSReceiver","Message recieved");
```

My Manifest file is as follows

```
<service android:name=".VolumeService"/>
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

I have both the permission and the intent filter so im not sure whats causing the issue. Im sending the text using telnet to send to the emulated device.Thanks

Comment: try to debug if your receiver get called when you send massage..

Comment: How would I go about doing this. Where would I check that's between the message being sent and my reciever getting called. I have my log set up as the first step of my reciever so it should appear as soon as my reliever is calles

Comment: Put a break point at your receiver and send message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the new sdk 23 permission system. Essentially permission for sms needs to be granted at runtime for an app now. Currently reverted back to sdk 22 but working on a fix for sdk 23